# Java compiler asking for semicolon

Tags: java, android

I've looked through this code for awhile, counted brackets, all that stuff. And I can't find an error. I'm using Eclipse, developing for Android, and it's asking for a semicolon (commented, it's near the bottom).

```
package com.example.lesson1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class TextPlay extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.text);

        final Button checkCommand = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
        final ToggleButton passToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbPassword);
        final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
        final TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);

        passToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (passToggle.isChecked()) {
                    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                            | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                } else {
                    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                }

            }
        });
        checkCommand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                String check = input.getText().toString();
                if (check.toLowerCase().equals("boss")) {
                    display.setText("Yup, pretty damn boss!");
                } else if (check.toLowerCase().equals("password")) {
                    display.setText("Simple");
                }
            }
        }); // here is the semicolon it wants
    }

}
```

Screenshot: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/986549/error.png

Comment: It wants a semicolon because `checkCommand.setOnClickListener(...);` is a statement.

Comment: His problem is that the semicolon is right there and he's still getting the error.

Comment: I can give it as many as i want, it doesn't change it. That must mean there's a problem of not closing brackets or something, but i've counted the brackets numerous times and they're all closed properly.

Comment: @AlexG: Ok, well in situations like this, one approach is to selectively comment out chunks of code until the problem goes away.  Once it goes away, the syntax error was in the last chunk of code you removed.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked just fine the way it is =/

Comment: Yup, agreed with @Hasslarn. Copied your code to a project of my own and there is no semicolon error.

Comment: Yeah, i'm pretty sure that this is all correct. I've tried commenting out as much as i can...it doesn't fix it. I never thought i'd say this (and still probably shouldn't), but is it possible the compiler's wrong? And if so, what then?

Comment: Incidentally, you should either include the _compiler_ output that shows the error message, or you should include a screenshot of the IDE that is giving you the highlighting error. (Or whatever it is that is giving you the error if it isn't easy to copy-and-paste here.)

Comment: Did the screenshot approach. Underneath code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try going into Project > clean. See if that gets rid of the error. Also, keep the semicolon.

Comment: and the almighty clean does do. thank you!

Comment: Do you think it should be answer rather than comment?

Comment: It solved the issue stated in the question so it is an answer.